# SQL - WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, subquery, where-clause, exists

I have a table with employees
**ID NAME SALARY**

and I am getting the employee with the most salary with this SQL statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM Emplyees eOut
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM Emplyees eIn 
                  WHERE eIn.Salary > eOut.Salary)
```

as I know the outer statement will be executed only if the inner one is true, so why this gives a result?
I do not understand why there is only one result for this, how is this processed and why NOT and > is important for that?

Comment: Look up the documentation in your database for "correlated subquery".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression:

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Emplyees eIn WHERE eIn.Salary > eOut.Salary)
```

is a Boolean expression with possible values `true` or `false`.
It gets the value `false` when the inner query returns (at least) 1 row and `true` if the inner query returns no rows.

Your assumption:

> the outer statement will be executed only if the inner one is true

as it is phrased is wrong.

The statement:

```
SELECT * FROM Emplyees eOut
```

will be executed and return **all** the rows of the table `Emplyees` and for each of these rows the `WHERE` clause will evaluate its condition to `true` or `false`.
So for every row of the table the condition `NOT EXISTS ...` will decide if that row will be in the final results or not.

To understand why *NOT and > is important* in this case, think of the query like this:

> Select every employee for whom does not exist another employee with
> greater salary.

Answer (score 1):

The query retuerns Employees. But not all of them, it does not show employee if there exists any employee that has higher salary than this one. The inner query is evaluated for every employee. In other words it returns employee with the highest salary. It may return more rows if two employees have the same highest salary.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
    FROM Emplyees 
    ORDER BY Salaray DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Try this Query